# Недоступен import во Vue SSR

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

**Я пытаюсь** разобраться во Vue SSR и вообще в node.js. У меня проблема с использованием `import`. В [официальной документации](https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/guide/structure.html#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2n%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8) мне не хватает подробностей.

До этого работал с vue-cli. Там вся структура строилась сама с помощью одной команды, а теперь мне приходится делать это самому, поэтому я испытываю трудности. В качестве сервера использую express

**Допустим у меня есть 3 файла:**

1. main.js - точка входа во всё приложение, запускает сервер и обслуживает запросы
2. app.js - содержит функцию, которая создаёт экземпляр Vue и возвращает его
3. App.vue - шаблон для экземпляра Vue (думаю не особо важно какой тут код будет, главное импортировать этот шаблон в app.js)

**main.js:**

```
// createApp - функция которая создаёт экземпляр Vue
const createApp = require('./app')
const server = require('express')()
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const context = { url: req.url }
    // Создать экземпляр Vue
    const app = createApp(context)

    renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).end('Внутренняя ошибка сервера')
            return
        }
        res.end('\
            <!DOCTYPE html> \
            <html lang="en"> \
                <meta charset="UTF-8"> \
                <head><title>Привет</title></head> \
                <body>' + html + '</body> \
            </html> \
        ')
    })
})

server.listen(8080)
```

**app.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// функция которая создаёт экземпляр Vue
export function createApp () {
    const app = new Vue({
        render: h => h(App)
    })
    return { app }
}
```

**При попытке** запустить всё это дело я получаю: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Нагуглил, что для использования `import` я должен указать в package.json `"type": "module"`, но тогда перестаёт работать `require`.

**В [документации](https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/guide/structure.html#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2n%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8)** они резко перестали показывать код для express, когда появился `import`. Это вводит в заблуждение и становится непонятно как я теперь должен всё это организовывать. Да, я понимаю, что там говорится про webpack, но из него нигде ничего не импортируется, я пробовал его устанавливать, это не помогает.

**Что я должен** сделать, чтобы это работало или как я должен изменить код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это было сложно, мне помогла разобраться вот эта [статья](https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/five-steps-to-vue-ssr/).

В документации рассказали самые элементарные основы, а как это всё собрать вместе непонятно. То что показано в документации это просто цветочки, а в реальном проекте приходится иметь дело со сложными конфигурациями webpack, кучей незнакомых модулей, которые непонятно что делают, кучей ошибок, несовместимостей и сохранением Vue приложения в формате JSON. Последнее для меня стало просто сногшибательным открытием, кто и как смог до этого додуматься? Это же просто треш =)